# Sort by Matrix Field

Tags: matrix

I was using this code in the past and it worked well

```
        {% set assets = craft.assets.limit(null) %}
        {% set entries = craft.entries.section('menu').limit(3).order('RAND()').relatedTo({
            targetElement: assets,
            field: 'assets'
        }) %}

        {% for item in entries %}
                {% set i = item.assets.first() %}

                <img width="{{ i.getWidth('medium') }}" height="{{ i.getHeight('medium') }}" src="{{ i.getUrl('medium') }}" alt="{{ recipe.title }}" />

        {% endfor %}
```

However, in the new version the standalone "assets" field became a part of the matrix field so this piece of code doesn't work anymore. Please advise :)

Answer (score 1):

You can access the assets field by referencing the matrix field first. `myMatrixFieldHandle.assets`.  So your entries code would be something like this.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('menu').limit(3).order('RAND()').relatedTo({
       targetElement: assets,
       field: 'myMatrixFieldHandle.assets'
}) %}
```

Comment: Thanks but I've got this error instead. Craft\EntryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "assets".

Comment: It would be whatever you named your assets field.

Comment: In my case the matrix fieldtype called "contentBuilder" and assets field name is "image.

    {% set assets = craft.assets.limit(null) %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.section('menu').limit(3).order('RAND()').relatedTo({
       targetElement: assets,
       field: 'contentBuilder.image'
}) %}

    {% for item in entries %}
    {% set i = item.image.first() %}
    <img src="{{ i.getUrl('medium') }}" />
    {% endfor %}